# Pull timer value from a webpage using xPath and C#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to pull some timer values off of websites using the xpath in the HtmlAgilityPack. However, when I am using the xpath, I get null reference exceptions because a particular node does not exist when I am grabbing it. To test why this was, I used a doc.Save to check the nodes myself, and I found that the nodes truly do not exist. From my understanding, HtmlAgilityPack should download the webpage almost exactly how I see it, with all the data in there as well. However, most of the data in fact is missing.

How exactly am I supposed to grab the timer values, or even an event title from either of the following websites:

http://dulfy.net/2014/04/23/event-timer/

http://guildwarstemple.com/dragontimer/eventsb.php?serverKey=108&langKey=1

My current code to pull just the title of the event from the first timebox from guildwarstemple is:

```
public void updateEventData()
{
    //string Url = "http://dulfy.net/2014/04/23/event-timer/";
    string Url = "http://guildwarstemple.com/dragontimer/eventsb.php?serverKey=108&langKey=1";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

    doc.Save("c:/doc.html");
    Title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='ep1']/p")[0].InnerText;
    //*[@id="scheduleList"]/div[3]
    //*[@id="scheduleList"]/div[3]/div[3]/text()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You XPath expression fails because there is only *one* `div` with `@id='ep1'` in the document, and it has *no* `p` inside:

```
<div id="ep1" class="eventTimeBox"></div>
```

In fact, *all* the `div`s in `megaContainer` are empty in the link you are trying to load with your code.

If you think there should be `p` elements in there, it's probably being added dynamically via JavaScript, so it might not be available when you are scraping the site with a C# client.

In fact, there are some JavaScript variables:

```
<script>
...
var e7 = 'ep1';
...
var e7t = '57600';
...
```

Maybe you want to get that data. This:

```
substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//script[contains(.,"var e7t")]),"var e7t = '"),"'")
```

selects the `<script>` which contains `var e7t` and extracts the string in the apostrophes. It will return:

```
57600
```

The same with your other link. The expression:

```
//*[@id="scheduleList"]
```

is a an empty `div`. You can't navigate further inside it:

```
<div id="scheduleList" style="width: 720px; min-width: 720px; background: #1a1717; color: #656565;"></div>
```

But this time there seems to be no nested JavaScript that refers to it in the page.

Comment: I was able to grab all the variables at one time by removing the substring-before(etc... stuff and just grabbing the script essentially. I was not able to get the functions to work, but that is probably due to my own lack of knowledge of xpath. Should I place that line into my xpath as a single string?